# javascript: get subarray from an array by indexes

Tags: javascript

Is there a one-line code to get an subarray from an array by index?

For example, suppose I want to get `["a","c","e"]` from `["a","b","c","d","e"]` by `[0,2,4]`. How to do this with a one-line code? Something like `["a","b","c","d","e"][0,2,4]`..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use `map`;

```js
var array1 = ["a","b","c"];
var array2 = [0,2];
var array3 = array2.map(i => array1[i]);
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: I actually like this better than my answer. Probably faster as well.

Comment: Is there a way so you don't have to traverse the array? Like a direct extraction from indexes or something like that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const indexes = [0, 2];

const result = arr.filter((elt, i) => indexes.indexOf(i) > -1);

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @NinaScholz OP doesn't ask for this

Comment: `const indexes = [2, 2];` try this @klugjo

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL: That's pretty silly input considering what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: It does work, it returns ['c'], which is what we want I am guessing. Question doesn't say

Comment: I'm just answer for klugjo question : 'What do you mean?', Opps  @NinaScholz's question  deleted .

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of `Array#filter` and `Array#includes`

```js
const array = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(array.filter((x,i) => [0,2].includes(i)));
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Although I'd have used a variable for the indexes array.

Comment: @Cerbrus I first wrote it with a variable but then I thought it was more visual to have it inline

Comment: Fair enough :-) Either way, +1

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for your comment ! Always nice to receive compliment :-D

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const indexes = [0, 2, 4];

const result = indexes.reduce((a, b)=> {
a.push(arr[b]);
return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```